# How to use chmod in ~/.bashrc

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-14.04, chmod, sys

I would like to change the permission of a file in the /sys directory but the permissions keep reseting after reboot. I tried to add a chmod in the ~/.bashrc so the permission would change upon booting, but I get an error (operation not permited) in terminal. What would be the right way to do this ? Does the ~/.bashrc get executed as root ?

This is my command in ~/.bashrc

```
chmod 664 /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

And this is the error I get:

```
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness’
: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Did you try to add `chmod` to `/root/.bashrc` or `/home/root/.bashrc` (up to your OS)?

Comment: If the /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness file already opened by any other process you get this operation not permitted error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~/.bashrc` is run as the user when the user logs in.  It is not run on boot.

If you want to change the permissions on a file, you need to have permission to do so.  The message is telling you that you don't have permission -- only root can do so.

The simplest way to do something custom on boot-up is to stick it in the file `/etc/rc.local`.  This script is run by root after booting up (so on every reboot), so you can just stick your chmod command in there.

Comment: The file does not have a permission it gives the permission denied error. Not operation not permitted.

Comment: @sureshkumar: "Operation not permitted" is EPERM -- "Permission denied" is EACCES.  EPERM is the errro generated by chmod if you don't have permission to change permissions.  EACCES would be generated if you don't have permission to access some directory on the path...